Purpose of NPN transistors in this ESP32 circuit
I am wondering what is the purpose of the two NPN transistors Q4 in the circuit below.

(full circuit schematic)
In this circuit, which is from an eval board for the ESP32-S3 microcontroller, IO0 and EN refer to input pins on an ESP32-S3 module not shown here.  They control whether the chip boots into its bootloader/programming mode (IO0, active low) and chip reset (EN, active high).
What is achieved by these two NPN transistors in this configuration?  Is there a reason why the USB-UART IC's DTR and RTS pins can't just drive the IO's on the microntroller directly?

you don't want them connected when the uart is not in use because it wastes battery or the uart defaults to a state that prevents the esp from booting.

The top transistor is only on if DTR is low and RTS is high. If DTR is low and RTS is high then IO0 sees the low DTR voltage but EN does not see the high RTS voltage (instead it is pulled up by an internal pull-up in the ESP32-3 circuitry or an external pull-up resistor not shown in your schematic). Similarly, if DTR is high and RTS is low then IO0 does not see the high DTR voltage. In all cases, minimal current flows from the ESP32-3 to the CP2102N (transistor on implies low voltage at both collector and emitter).  This would also prevent EN and IO0 being simultaneously low (if that matters).

It's already discussed here, back in 2017. Did you try and do a search before asking this question, using DTR and RTS?
